# Installing python pip for docker container doesnt work

Tags: docker, pip

I'm trying to configure python-pip for my docker container(s). But it gives me the error that I dont have permission. After I use sudo, it gives me an another error.

I'v tried using sudo for root permission. I aslo tried the command exec and run.

```
sudo docker container run davidrazd/discord-node-10 sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo docker container exec davidrazd/discord-node-10 sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"sudo\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

And without sudo:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
>
> E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: You usually don't install software in a running container: as soon as the container exits, this will be lost, and you'll have to repeat it.  Put install steps like this in a Dockerfile instead and build a custom image containing your software.

Comment: How can I modify a docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 3 reasons I think you should reconsider your use of Docker and make sure you're getting the most out of containers.

1. you have an image called `...-node-10`.  You shouldn't need specific images for specific nodes.  They should all run on the same image and, to the extent necessary, be configured at runtime (this should be kept to a minimum, usually things like discovery or dynamic config).  If `10` is a version, you should be using tags to version it, not image ID itself.
2. There's a valid use case for one-off execution of an install within a running container via `exec` for one-off package installs (knowing that the install will disappear when the container stops), but `docker run ... apt-get install` really doesn't make sense to me.  As @DavidMaze points out in a question comment, installs that are meant to be should always be part of the Dockerfile.  If you're installing packages to long-lived containers - don't, and don't.  The worst things that happen to folks with docker is they attempt to treat containers as long lived Virtual Machines, when they should be treating them as *ephemeral runtime environments* that maintain minimal state, are essentially immutable ( and therefore easily replaced by the next version), their image contains all their install-time dependencies, and store any long term data on a separate docker volume (that hopefully is itself backed up).
3. You're likely configuring a user your application to run as a USER in your Dockerfile but you're attempting to run privileged commands without setting your USER to something else.  Then you attempt to run `sudo`.  But `sudo` doesn't make much sense in the context of a container, and typically is not installed (and if it was, it would mean you'd have to somehow set up a user to sudo, so it wouldn't make your life any easier, just harder).  You can set your user at `docker exec` time to `root` with `docker exec -u root ...`.  But you shouldn't really need to do this - all setup should be done in the Dockerfile and you should ship a new dockerfile to change versions.

I'm a very heavy user of docker myself, and build nearly all applications in it becuse it so vastly simplifies expressing their runtime requirements, so I think I speak from the voice of experience here.  You won't get any of the value of docker if your containers aren't immutable; you'll just have the same problems as you would without containers, but with less management tooling.  Docker obviates most of the management at runtime - capitalize on that, don't fight it.